# Convert an array of 2-element arrays to an array making 2 elements as key => value

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to convert the following array using some PHP built-in functions to a array that contain the value of `id` as key and the value of `label` as the associated value? If not what's the efficient way?

Thanks.

Input Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [label] => MTD-589
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [label] => MTD-789
        )

)
```

Output Array:

```
Array
(
  [2] => MTD-589,
  [3] => MTD-789,
)
```

Comment: I was looking for built-in functions, PHP has lots of them to work with arrays. but found nothing yet

Comment: This feature is probably the one you want as implemented in 5.5: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/array_column but sadly that's still in beta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introducing [array_column](http://benramsey.com/blog/2013/03/introducing-array-column-in-php-5-dot-5/) (still in PHP 5.5 Beta).

```
$new_array = array_column($your_array 'label', 'id');
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Array
(
  [2] => MTD-589,
  [3] => MTD-789,
)
```

Using [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

```
array_walk($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[$a['id']] = $a['label']; });
print_r($return);
```

Comment: As I have already given in a comment to the main post. However, as it's still in Beta, you can't count this as a valid answer yet.

Comment: @Anyone - Yeah I mention it in my answer. Can be used for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any built in function, but I'll do it this way:

assuming `$originalArray` as the array you want to convert

```
$newArray = array();

foreach ($originalArray as $element)
     $newArray[$element["id"]] = $element["label"];
```

output the result

```
var_dump($newArray);
```

Comment: doen't work! I can think of doing it using just one for loop. why two? I think I'd apply that if I don't find a way to do using built-ins

Answer (score 0):

if you can make it so that one array has your IDs and one array has your labels, you can use array_combine to merge the two as key/value http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php