# Merge two multidimensional associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have these two arrays that I would like to merge together into 1 array but been having a hard time figuring out. See below for the two snippets of code:

First array:

```
$propSelectMaxRow = max(array_keys($property_select_email));
$i = 0;
foreach($property_queue as $r) {
    if ($select_type == 3 || $select_type == 4 || $select_type == 5) {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $property_select_email[$propSelectMaxRow + $i] = $r;
    }
}
```

Second array:

```
$propSelectMaxRow = max(array_keys($property_select_email));
$i = 0;
foreach($property_select as $r) {
    if ($select_type == 1 || $select_type == 2 || $select_type == 4 || $select_type == 5) {
        $i = $i + 1;
        $property_select_email[$propSelectMaxRow + $i] = $r;
    }
}
```

edit: 
I would like the final array to look like this:

first array format:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( [code] => PPJ3 [street] => 34412 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 ) 

    [2] => Array ( [code] => PLK3 [street] => 73517 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 ) 

    [3] => Array ( [code] => HYK2 [street] => 55224 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48208 ) 
 )
```

Second array format:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( [code] => JAK932 [street] => 353242 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 ) 

    [2] => Array ( [code] => JA232 [street] => 7432 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 ) 
 )
```

Final array format should be:

```
Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( [code] => PPJ3 [street] => 34412 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 ) 

    [2] => Array ( [code] => PLK3 [street] => 73517 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 ) 

    [3] => Array ( [code] => HYK2 [street] => 55224 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48208 ) 

    [4] => Array ( [code] => JAK932 [street] => 353242 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 ) 

    [5] => Array ( [code] => JA232 [street] => 7432 Fake Street [city] => Detroit [state] => MI [zip] => 48223 ) 
 )
```

Comment: you should post var_dump of both the arrays and an ipotetic var_dump of how you'd like the merge to be. Just like this guy did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16215479/convert-an-array-of-2-element-arrays-to-an-array-making-2-elements-as-key-val/

Comment: Since you don't state how you actually want it to look, going to say [`array_merge`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) is a nice function.

Comment: @jon i went ahead and edited my post.

Comment: @justWired Yep, [`array_merge`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) would get it like that for you - though re-indexed starting at 0.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to improve your code like this:

```
//$propSelectMaxRow = max(array_keys($property_select_email)); // no need
//$i = 0; //no need
foreach($property_queue as $r) {
    if ($select_type == 3 || $select_type == 4 || $select_type == 5) {
        //$i = $i + 1;
        $property_select_email[] = $r;
    }
}
```

Similarly, build your second array. The second loop will be append array at the end of first (hence they will be auto merged).

Comment: `var_dump($property_select_email)` at the end so we could see what you got after it.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you just need to use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge)